# dynamically arrange md-dialog labels

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, flexbox, angular-material

My tab dialog looks like this:

[image]

As you can see the tabs ("DESCRIPTION,MEANS,...) are not arranged evenly through the available space. I tried the flex directive but it won't work.

My html is this (shortened) :

```
    <md-toolbar>
  <div class="md-toolbar-tools">
    <h2>{{error}}</h2>
    <span flex></span>
    <md-button class="md-icon-button" ng-click="cancel()">
      <md-icon md-svg-src="../../../assets/img/close.svg" aria-label="Close dialog"></md-icon>
    </md-button>
  </div>
</md-toolbar>
<md-dialog-content style="max-width:800px;max-height:1400px;min-width:800px; ">
  <md-tabs md-dynamic-height md-border-bottom>
    <md-tab label="description">
      <md-content class="md-padding">
        <h1 class="md-display-2">Description</h1>
        <p flex>{{description}}</p>
      </md-content>
    </md-tab>
    <md-tab label="means">
      <md-content class="md-padding">
        <h1 class="md-display-2">Means</h1>
        <p>{{means}}</p>
      </md-content>
    </md-tab>
```

Is there any way to achieve this kind of label arrangement that I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add  md-stretch-tabs="always" in  md-tabs   [check this](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdTabs)